# Create a QModelIndex from a Data Item

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

I'm looking for a way to create a QModelIndex from a particular piece of data in my model. I can go from a QModelIndex to a data item via:

```
CustomData *data = static_cast<CustomData *>(modelIndex.internalPointer());
```

But I'm looking for an inverse function to go from:

```
QModelIndex *index = createIndex(data); // ??
```

I've implemented linkages between my data very similar to the simple tree model example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html). My view displays the data correctly, but with considerable lag. I'd like to emit dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex) to see updates to the view instantly, since I think the lag is due to waiting for the view to update.

In the linked example, I'm trying to get from a TreeItem to its corresponding index in the QTreeModel.

Comment: Please show the complete implementation of your model *and* of `CustomData`.

Answer (score 2):

The view doesn't update periodically. It updates as needed, and from the point of view of your model, that means anything. If your model doesn't emit `dataChanged` when an item changes one or more of its data role values, then your model is simply broken.

To fix it, you have two approaches:

1. Add the row and column to `CustomData`. You'll have to keep these updated as you add/remove rows/columns.
2. When needed, iterate the items in the parent of your item to find the child - when you do, you get the row/column from the loop that iterates the items.

I think that you're trying too hard, through. You most likely do not need to implement `CustomData` at all - but merely use `QStandardItem` and store the data in the variant. Then, `QStandardItemModel` handles all the details of iterators and signals for you. To store a custom data type in the `QVariant` that the `QStandardItem` uses for storage, simply expose it to the `QVariant` machinery via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(YourType)`.

You'd need to provide a convincing argument that somehow a `QStandardItem` is insufficient for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use traditional indicies because in the Model/View programming they don't stick around, unless you use:

`QPersistentModelIndex`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html#details

Also there are a lot of new paradigms introduced with the Model/View programming.  The documentation on it and using it has a learning curve... read through it a few times and try using the examples bundled with Qt Creator that use them.

### More about using `QPersistentModelIndex`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-model-indexes

> Model indexes provide temporary references to pieces of information,
>   and can be used to retrieve or modify data via the model. Since models
>   may reorganize their internal structures from time to time, model
>   indexes may become invalid, and should not be stored. If a long-term
>   reference to a piece of information is required, a persistent model
>   index must be created. This provides a reference to the information
>   that the model keeps up-to-date. Temporary model indexes are provided
>   by the `QModelIndex` class, and persistent model indexes are provided by
>   the `QPersistentModelIndex` class.
>
> To obtain a model index that corresponds to an item of data, three
>   properties must be specified to the model: a row number, a column
>   number, and the model index of a parent item...